# Alternative to Shannon's entropy when probability equal to zero

Tags: classification, entropy

I have a series of objects for which I know the probability of belonging to 10 classes. This probability can be null (see example below with 4 classes: A,B,C,D).

```
   A    B    C    D
1  0.4  0.0  0.2  0.4
2  0.1  0.3  0.4  0.2
3  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
```

In order to get for each object an information about the quality of the classification, I wanted to calculate Shannon's entropy but it does not work when one of the classes has a probability equal to zero (log(0)=-Inf).

My question: Is there a measure similar to Shannon's entropy (or an adaptation) which handles probabilities equal to zero?

Comment: The entropy is a sum of terms of the form $p\ log(p)$.  When $p=0$ you instead use the *limiting* value (as $p$ approaches $0$ from above), which is $0$.

Comment: @whuber thanks! I was searching for this. Do you know of a creditable reference?

Comment: nevermind, found it in MacKay's book: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/433096/252518

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ignore the zero probabilities, and carry on summation using the same equation.

```
for each object{ 
        double e=0.0;
        for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
            if (p[i]!=0)
                e = e+ p[i]*Log(p[i],2);
        }
        e=-1 * e;
    print e;
}
```

//
the entropy for rows 1,2 and 3 is 1.52, 1.85, and 0.00 respectively

Answer (score 9):

According to MacKay's book "Information Theory, Inference, and Learning Algorithms" (chapter 2), the convention is that you can equate to zero the terms including zero probabilities, as the other answers suggest. See an excerpt below:

[image: MacKay's definition of entropy]

Answer (score 0):

Ignore zero and carry out the computation.

```
entropyFunc =(data) ->
    H = 0
    for i of  data 
        #since the log function isnt defined at 0 
        if data[i] ? 0
            H += ( (-1) * data[i] * Math.log2(data[i]) )
    return H
```

Comment: This does not seem to add anything to the already accepted answer.

Comment: @mdewey I think it adds possible slogan for t-shirt:
"Ignore the Zero And Carry On" :)

Comment: What do you mean @Tim?

Comment: @Tim, you know when we write an answer to help someone we do not care much about English proofreading.

Comment: "when we write an answer to help someone we do not care much about English proofreading"; I dissent. Correct and well written English always lifts a contribution and the opposite doesn't help. Naturally we appreciate that accidents of birth and education make writing good English easy for some and difficult for others, but neither is a reason to despise or downplay it.

Answer (score 0):

for classification you can use gini index as an approximation to entropy $1-\sum p_i^2$ which behaves well at 0

Comment: This isn't an approximation to entropy at all. It's a different measure.