# What is the best function to fit onto a "flat top gaussian"?

Tags: gaussian-mixture-distribution, signal-processing, signal-detection

I am studying some signal and I am trying to make an automated algorithm that can extract the parameters for my signal.
First let me describe a bit, I have a light emiting object crossing a window of observation with a given speed. That object is an elipse, thus when I measure the signal I find something that looks like a flat top gaussian. (see scheme)

I have been using a Gaussian Mixture Model to describe it, but because the top is flatten, it finds many more distribution than what is actually there !
Thus I am looking for a mathematical function that could describe that kind of signal, so that I can implement a least square regression or something along those line.
Idealy that function would have a "variance" and a "mean" parameter such that I can make analysis about those two later on.
Thanks a lot !

[image: Scheme]

Comment: There is the "*Frankenstein*" distribution that is known as the [Johnson S_U distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson_SU_distribution). You can probably fit it so it looks like a a flat-top Gaussian but really... why?

Comment: The anwser to why, is research XD
I don't necessarily choose what my signal is going to look like ^^

Comment: This has a similar look. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/57069/alternative-to-shannons-entropy-when-probability-equal-to-zero

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have probably solved this problem, since this post is from a year ago. But just in case: is there a reason why you can't directly fit a flat-top Gaussian functional representation to your distribution? The general Gauss function is $g(x) = \exp[-(x/a)^n]$, "$a$" being the half-width at $1/e$. $n=2$ is a standard Gaussian, $n>2$ a flat-top Gaussian, and $n<2$ a peaked Gaussian.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing ! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Alright so I came up with a way to do it, it's kindof a hack:
Take the left part of a gaussian, plus a plateau, then the right side of the gaussian.

```
def multinomial_normal_fusion(x, params):
    # params here is a list of [mu_0, sigma_0, amplitude_0, spread_0, mu_1, ...]
    par = np.reshape(params, (len(params) / 4, 4))
    n = len(par)
    curve = np.zeros(len(x))
    for i in range(n):
        mu, sigma, k, spread = par[i]
        xi = np.searchsorted(x, mu)
        curve[0:xi] += k * scipy.stats.norm.pdf(x[0:xi], loc=mu, scale=sigma)
        xj = np.searchsorted(x, mu + spread)
        curve[xi:xj] += k * scipy.stats.norm.pdf([mu] * len(curve[xi:xj]), loc=mu, scale=sigma)
        curve[xj:] += k * scipy.stats.norm.pdf(x[xj:], loc=mu + spread, scale=sigma)
    return curve
```

If anyone has a better idea ? 
Thanks

Comment: Yes that's a bad idea. A much better idea would be what you would obtain if you convolved a Gaussian function with a rectangle, which would be something like `(erf(x-p1) - erf(x-p2))/2`, `p1` and `p2` being the positions of the edge of the 1D rectangle.